# How do I register observers in grpc cpp code and stream responses through them when an event occurs?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

So far I have been able to serve unary responses and streaming responses in cpp grpc code. What I cannot figure out is a way to be able to support publisher/subscriber pattern where clients register themselves to certain topics and when that corresponding event occurs, an update is pushed over all the registered streams. How do I maintain a registry of client connections and how to I trigger ServerWriter->write over those connections?

Comment: I'm using grpc with python, but I have a similar need, it'd be great to subscribe to events. My first approach was to maintain a open call with a busy wait that polls a buffer for each stream, but it is clearly poor design